# Как вывести на консоль значения(обьектов массива?) разного типа переменных из экземпляров класса

Tags: java

```
public class Ops {
    public String name;
    public int age; //создаю класс и его параметры

    public Ops(String name, int age ){
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age; //причисляю ему переменные
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name; //Получие имени
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name; //возврат в строку класса
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age; //те же яйца только в профиль
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class programm {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Ops[] array = new Ops[4];
    for(int i = 1; i<4; i++) {

        Scanner nameString = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = (nameString.nextLine());
        Scanner ageInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age = ageInt.nextInt();

        array[i] = new Ops(name, age);
        //System.out.print("Os:"+name);
        //System.out.print(" age:"+age + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    System.out.print("Список всех Ос." + System.lineSeparator() );
     for(int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    }
}
```

**не представляю как вывести на панель вывода все значения обьектов массива.**
при коде выводятся адреса классов, а не их значения, что мне нужно.
"Список всех Ос.
Ops@46f7f36a
Ops@421faab1
Ops@2b71fc7e"

Если не трудно - максимально подробно обьясните как правильно сделать, и что можно улучшить)

Comment: Переопределить метод toString

Comment: это как? можешь подробнее сказать?

Comment: В учебной литературе, ну или по крайней мере в гугле ищи.

Comment: Такими темпами нет смысла искать решения здесь. Тебя тут не обязан никто учить, а решение проблемы легко найти. Это база языка, и глупо ради такого заводить целый вопрос. Уважай себя, уважай других.

Comment: собственно зачем вообще подобный ресурс существует? м? задать вопрос - глупо) вообще вопросы задавать это глупо, так?

Comment: Ресурс для решения проблем, не для обучения. Вот и все.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java

Answer (score 1):

При попытке вызвать

```
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

происходит вызов метода, println (класс PrintStream):

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

В первой строке объект пребразуется в строковое представление:

```
String s = String.valueOf(x);
```

Если вы откроете реализацию этого метода в классе String, то увидите примерно следующее:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

у объекта вызывается метод toString()

У вашего объекта класса Ops нет такого метода. Но так как все классы наследуются от класса Object, то происходит вызов метода из этого класса. Открываем реализацию этого метода в классе Object:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

В вашем случае выполняется именно эта реализация метода, поэтому вы и получаете ответ вида "Ops@46f7f36a" и т.п.

Если вы хотите получить другой результат, то вам нужно переопределить метод toString() для класса Ops. Добавьте реализацию метода, например:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Ops{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: огромное спасибо за ответ!