# Когда нажимаю run выводит шифр

Tags: java

когда я нажимаю запуск у меня выводит какой то шифр
мой код:

```
public float speed;
public int weight;
public String color;
public byte[] coordinate;
мой код Main:
Transport truck;
truck = new Transport();
truck.speed = 70.14f;
truck.weight = 4000;
truck.color = "White";
truck.coordinate = new byte[] {6,54,91};
System.out.print(truck);
```

а сам вывод:Transport@5f184fc6

Comment: Все правильно выводит. Просто у вас в классе Transport не переопределен метод `toString()`

Comment: и что мне делать?

Comment: 1 - почитать зачем нужен метод toString() в своих классах. 2 - добавить этот метод в свой класс

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1175002/178576)?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести на консоль значения(обьектов массива?) разного типа переменных из экземпляров класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175002/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%ba)

Answer (score 0):

Вам возвращается хєшкод объекта. Если вы хотите видеть другую информацию, то для этого в классе Transport вам необходимо переопределить метод toString()

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "текст который вы хотите видеть";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `System.out.print(Object object)` трансформирует объект в строку с помощью метода `string Object.toString()`. По умолчанию этот метод возвращает `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. Если же вы хотите что бы данный метод выводил данные об объекте, то вам необходимо переопределить этот метод:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "speed: " + this.speed + "\n" +
         "weight: " + this.weight + ...;
}
```